# Bind dropdownlist to a list of table in each row using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to bind a dropdownlist which is of type `SelectListitem` to a list class that returns all the elements of the view model. However in my `ActionResult`'s `return View()` I'm only able to pass one item only, either `SelectListItem` or the list class itself.

Model:

```
public class NewTicket
{
    public int Ticket_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Issue_Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> technician { get; set; }
}
```

AdminController:

```
private SqlConnection con;

// To handle connection related activities    
private void connection()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskDBContext"].ToString();
    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
}

// To view all user ticket details with generic list
public List<NewTicket> GetAllUserTickets()
{
    connection();

    List<NewTicket> mytickets = new List<NewTicket>();
    string query = "SELECT TICKET.Employee_ID, EMPLOYEE.Employee_Name, Ticket_ID, Category_Name, Assigned_By, Assigned_To, Assigned_Date,Description, Issue_Date, STATUS_LOOKUP.Status_Type, Name, ImageAttachment FROM TICKET, CATEGORY, STATUS_LOOKUP, EMPLOYEE WHERE TICKET.Category_ID = CATEGORY.Category_ID AND TICKET.Status_ID = STATUS_LOOKUP.Status_ID AND TICKET.Employee_ID = EMPLOYEE.Employee_ID AND TICKET.Status_ID =2 ORDER BY Issue_Date DESC";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskDBContext"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow sdr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    TempData["tickID"] = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Ticket_ID"]);

                    mytickets.Add(new NewTicket
                        {
                            Ticket_ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Ticket_ID"]) ,
                            Employee_ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Employee_ID"]),
                            Employee_Name = sdr["Employee_Name"].ToString(),
                            Category_Name = sdr["Category_Name"].ToString(),
                            Description = sdr["Description"].ToString(),
                            Issue_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["Issue_Date"]),
                            Status_Type = sdr["Status_Type"].ToString(),
                            Name = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                           )
                        });
                }

                con.Close();
                return mytickets;
            }
        }
    }
}

// To select a value from dropdownlist
public List<SelectListItem> PopulateTechnician()
{ 
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskDBContext"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "SELECT LOGIN.ID , EMPLOYEE.Employee_Name FROM LOGIN, EMPLOYEE WHERE LOGIN.Employee_ID = EMPLOYEE.Employee_ID AND TechnicianRole = 1 AND AdminRole = 0";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new SelectListItem
                        { 
                            Text = sdr["Employee_Name"].ToString(),
                            Value = sdr["ID"].ToString()
                        });
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return items;
}

// This is the view where both the PopulateTechnician and GetAllUserTickets should be. However i can only return one item.
public ActionResult ChooseTechnician()
{
    NewTicket tick = new NewTicket();
    tick.technician = PopulateTechnician();

    return View(tick);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChooseTechnician(NewTicket tech)
{
    connection();
    tech.technician = PopulateTechnician();

    var selectedItem = tech.technician.Find(p => p.Value == tech.ID.ToString());
    var selectedticketid = tech.TicketIDList.Find(tick => tick.Ticket_ID == id);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Assign_Technician", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned_By", TempData.Peek("userTicket"));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned_To", selectedItem.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_ID", selectedticketid);

    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return RedirectToAction("AdminHome");
}
```

All tickets:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Ticket_ID)
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".my-row" class="clickable row-header" bgcolor="#010e2e">
     <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-target=".my-row" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
     </td>
     <td><h5><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ticket_ID) </b></h5></td>
     <td><h5><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category_Name)</b></h5></td>     
     <td><h5><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</b></h5></td>
     <td><h5><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Issue_Date)</b></h5></td>
     <td><h5><b>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "ChooseTechnician", new { id = item.Ticket_ID })</b></h5></td>
  </tr>
}
```

Choose technician:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, Model.technician, "Please select a technician")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind list of items or one item you need to alter the class as shown below.

```
public class NewTicket
{
  public NewTicket()
  {
    technician = new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
  public int Ticket_ID { get; set; }
  public DateTime Issue_Date { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }


  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
  public List<SelectListItem> technician { get; set; }
}
```

After that if you want to list item with drop down please change the code as shown below

```
public List<NewTicket> GetAllUserTickets()
{

    connection();
    var populateTechnician = PopulateTechnician();
    List<NewTicket> mytickets = new List<NewTicket>();
    string query = "SELECT TICKET.Employee_ID, EMPLOYEE.Employee_Name, Ticket_ID, Category_Name, Assigned_By, Assigned_To, Assigned_Date,Description, Issue_Date, STATUS_LOOKUP.Status_Type, Name, ImageAttachment FROM TICKET, CATEGORY, STATUS_LOOKUP, EMPLOYEE WHERE TICKET.Category_ID = CATEGORY.Category_ID AND TICKET.Status_ID = STATUS_LOOKUP.Status_ID AND TICKET.Employee_ID = EMPLOYEE.Employee_ID AND TICKET.Status_ID =2 ORDER BY Issue_Date DESC";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskDBContext"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow sdr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var item = new NewTicket
                    {

                        Ticket_ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Ticket_ID"]) ,
                        Employee_ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Employee_ID"]),
                        Employee_Name = sdr["Employee_Name"].ToString(),
                        Category_Name = sdr["Category_Name"].ToString(),
                        Description = sdr["Description"].ToString(),
                        Issue_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["Issue_Date"]),
                        Status_Type = sdr["Status_Type"].ToString(),
                        Name = sdr["Name"].ToString(),                           
                    };
                    TempData["tickID"] = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Ticket_ID"]);
                    item.technician.AddRange(populateTechnician);


                    mytickets.Add(item);
                }

                con.Close();
                return mytickets;
            }
        }
    }
}

 /// action for list all

public ActionResult AllUserTickets()
{

    var getAllUserTickets = GetAllUserTickets();

    return View(getAllUserTickets);

}
```

and generate list view 'AllUserTickets'  for all tickets and change this code as shown below

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(item=> item.ID, item.technician, "Please select a technician")
```

**For individual you need to do as it like**

```
public ActionResult ChooseTechnician()
{

     NewTicket tick = new NewTicket();
     tick.technician = PopulateTechnician();

    return View(tick);

}
```

**NB: Add Create view for ticket and choose dropdownlist as you used**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChooseTechnician(NewTicket tech)
{

    connection();
    tech.technician = PopulateTechnician();

    var selectedItem = tech.technician.Find(p => p.Value == tech.ID.ToString());
    var selectedticketid = tech.TicketIDList.Find(tick => tick.Ticket_ID == id);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Assign_Technician", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned_By", TempData.Peek("userTicket"));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assigned_To", selectedItem.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_ID", selectedticketid);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();


    return RedirectToAction("AdminHome");


}
```